# Bootstrap 4.0 order columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I am trying to build the following layout with bootstrap 4, I would like 2 bigger columns on the left and then 4 grouped together on the right but their height togetehr cannot exceed the heigth of the first 2.

Except I just cant get it to work.

This is what I want:

[image]

This is basically what I got:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrBpze

```
<section id="mu-featured">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="" style="height: 235px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                        unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="" style="height: 235px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                        unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                        unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                        unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                        unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                        unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: and what have you tried to solve this problem ? i see that all cols have the same classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify how they should behave on smaller screens, but to answer your question: You need to nest the right-most items like shown in the code below.

In other words, what you are looking to do is called "nesting". Not ordering.

To nest, you put a `.row` into a column and then put at least one other `col-*` inside that nested row (the second code snippet further down below produces a slightly different result):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="mu-featured">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/235" alt="" style="height: 235px">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                    unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                    unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                    unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/235" alt="" style="height: 235px">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                    unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                    unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil
                    unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                        iste neque ratione libero.  <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here's another version that produces a slightly different result (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="mu-featured">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/235" alt="" style="height: 235px">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/235" alt="" style="height: 235px">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-100"></div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-100"></div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-100"></div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/85" alt="" style="height: 85px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a></p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In that second code snippet, the small images and their text content are separated in 2 different columns and `<div class="w-100"></div>` is used as a separator for small screens. `w-100` means "width:100%".

Comment: In the second code snippet I just added, the small images and their text content are separated in 2 different columns and `<div class="w-100"></div>` is used as a separator.

Comment: Thanks this did exactly what I wanted! I edited it a little bit to what I wanted with the pictures, except one thing I dont understand is how I can match the width of images to the width of the column its in.

https://jsfiddle.net/ggqt15zm/4/

This was my idea for the smaller screens by the way but I wanted to focus on desktop first and then later work on the smaller screens. No idea if thats the right way to do it.
https://imgur.com/a/SbFb1